# Как заставить программу ждать ответа Ajax-запроса с сервера?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Как мне из запроса вида:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://server/',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(resp) {
        //Обработка данных и вызов дальнейших функций
    }
});
//остальной скрипт
```

Сделать запрос вида:

```
var responseData = Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://server/',
    method: 'POST'
}).getData();
//остальной скрипт
```

В первом варианте, после выполнения `Ext.Ajax.request(.....`, программа продолжает свое выполнение, и через некоторое время срабатывает функция `success: function(resp) {...`. 
**Вопрос**:
Как мне сделать что-то похожее на второй вариант, когда программа, дойдя до `var responseData =`, ждала момента, когда придет ответ с сервера, инициализировала переменную `responseData`, и продолжала дальше выполнять следующие скрипты (команды).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если бы вы понимали как работает JavaScript - вы бы поняли что это невозможно. Вернее это возможно, но для этого нужно использовать костыли аля `setInterval` и в нем проверять пока данные не прийдут, или синхронный ajax, но это глупо. Кстати - а чем вас не устраивает первый вариант?

Если необходимо прекратить какие-то события на странице или нечто подобное достаточно прост о ввести переменную вида `var requestComplete = false;` в обработчиках проверять ее на true, ну и при ответе сервера - изменять ее на true.

В любом случае, без callback'a, без жертвы асинхронностью или без костыля setInterval вам не обойтись.

PS: зачем все так усложнять? `=\`

*keep it simple...*

---

Допустим, пока не пришел ответ сервера - все обработчики должны "уснуть", при этом и ежу понятно что очищать, а потом снова записывать - глупо. Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
// под ext перепишите сами, я пишу по w3c стандартам
var __requestComplete = false;
// этим методом будет навешивать запросо-зависимые обработчики событий
function addRequestWaitHandler(eventName, handler) {
     this.addEventListener(eventName, function(e){
          if(__requestComplete) { // если ответ от сервера получен
                handler(e);       // выполняем обработчик
          }
     })
}
// например навесим запросо-зависимы обработчик на нажатие жлемента с id lol
addRequestWaitHandler.call(document.getElementById("lol"), "click", function(e){
     alert("I was clicked");
})

// ну и соответственно код запроса будет выглядеть примерно так:
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://server/',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(resp) {
        __requestComplete = true;
        // ответ от сервера получен - теперь все обработчики
        // запросо-зависимых событий будут выполнятся
    }
});
```

Идея примерно такая, конечно если не писать функцию для навешивания таких обработчиков и навешивать напрямую то все будет выглядеть еще проще, т.е.:

```
function requestWaitFunction(func) {
     if(__requesComplete) {
          func();
     }
} 
// ну и, например
document.getElementById("lol").onclick = function(e){
     requestWaitFunction(function(e){
          // тут код обработчика
     })
}
// или просто =)
document.getElementById("lol").onclick = function(e) {
     if(__requestComplete ) {
          // тут код обработчика
          // но это не крута =(
     }
}
```

В любом случае, если использовать подобный подход, по сути, вы можете "усыпить" и снова разбудить все запросо-зависимые обработчики изменением значения одной единственной переменной

---

Реализация для возможности навешивания обработчиков на изменение __requestComplete, для этого можно сделать что-то тип:

```
var requestUtil = (function(){
     completeListeners = [];
     waitListeners = [];
     return {
          __completed: false,
          comlete: function(){
              this.__completed = true;
              for(var i=0, l=completeListeners.length; i<l; ++i) {
                  completeListeners[i]();
              }
          },
          wait: function(){
              this.__completed = false;
              for(var i=0, l=waitListeners.length; i<l; ++i) {
                  waitListeners[i]();
              }
          },
          addComleteListener(func) {
               completeListeners.push(func);
          },
          addWaitListener(func) {
               waitListeners.push(func);
          }
     }
})();

// соответственно:

window.onload = function(){
     // навешиваем обработчики как-то так:
     requestUtil.addCompleteListener(function(){
          alert("RequestCompleted");
     });
     requestUtil.addWaitListener(function(){
          alert("RequestWaiting");
     });
     requestUtil.wait(); // ожидаемт ответа сервера

     Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://server/',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(resp) {
            requestUtil.complete(); // ответ сервера пришел
        }
     });
}
```

Возможно где-то есть ошибки, но суть, надеюсь. ясна. В любом случае я и так написал достаточно много, разбирайтесь =)

Comment: >> Если необходимо прекратить какие-то события на странице или нечто подобное достаточно прост о ввести переменную вида var requestComplete = false; в обработчиках проверять ее на true, ну и при ответе сервера - изменять ее на true.  

Можно поподробнее про этот вариант? Т.е. как мне установить обрабтчик. Не ясно, как можно, изменив переменную на true, заставить что-то делаться.

Comment: Не понял. Т.е. теперь, как только изменится `__requestComplete` на `true`, будет выполняться `requestWaitFunction`?  
Или все-же надо будет кликать и кликать по элементу 'lol', и действия никакого не будет, пока, наконец, не придет ответ с сервера?  
А если все-же после того, как нажали на кнопку, пошел запрос на сервер, и как только `__requestComplete` стало `true`, выполнять свою функцию?

Comment: Эту задачу мне решать лениво, ибо будет много кода, над которым еще и думать прийдется.

Нет, если вы добавили обработчик с проверкой условия - обработчик просто не будет выполнятся. Судя по тому как вы написали ваш вопрос - задачу я понял именно так.

В любом случае - если не получается или сложно сделать по нормальному, всегда можно сделать синхронный ajax и не заморачиватся.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, хотя-бы идею, как можно повесить обработчик на изменение переменной `__requestComplete`. Если бы не одна сложность, возникающая при вызове обработчика именно таким способом, у меня бы вопрос такой не возник.