# return в ajax

Tags: ajax

```
function get_settings(ans){

     var request = getXmlHttp(); // глобальная переменная
     var answer;
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            return request.responseText;    
             /*alert(request.responseText)*/
        }

    }

    request.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("act=get_set&ans="+ans);
}
```

как `return`'уть `request.responseText`?

`alert (get_settings('info'))` выдает undefined

а если снять кавычки (/**/)  выдает то что нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемы с мат-частью... Только что описывал нечто подобное.
В общем для того чтобы ваш код работал:

```
function get_settings(ans){
     var request = getXmlHttp(); // глобальная переменная
     var answer;
     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            onRequestComlete(request.responseText);   
        }
    }

    request.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("act=get_set&ans="+ans);
}

function onRequestComplete(data) { // обработчик ответа сервера
     alert(data);
     // сдесь пишите код который должен отработать после получения
     // данных от сервера
}
```

Если вам необходимо что-бы скрипт "засыпал" пока нет ответа от сервера используйте синхронный запрос, либо что-то из описанного мною [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/68795/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Теперь объясню почему то что написали вы гдупость: onreadystatechange это событие и ваш код

```
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        return request.responseText;
    }
```

Выполняется тогда когда это событие наступает, более того - еще и при доп.условиях, вообщем модель асинхронного ajax запроса заключаеться в событийной ориентированости, т.е. у вас нет возможности написать линейный код, вы должны описывать код цепочками событий, либо, как я уже писал, используйте синхронный ajax (его и придумали для того чтобы можно было писать линейный код)

---

я же написал - для этого используйте синхронный(блокирующий) ajax запрос, на момент его выполнения страница какбы подвисает (причем если в этот момент разрывается соединение IE7- не отвечают), но тогда вы сможете написать то что вы хотите.

Чтобы сделать с использованием синхронного ajax запроса:

```
 function get_settings(ans){
     var request = getXmlHttp(); // глобальная переменная
     var answer;
     windows.status("ожидание ответа сервера...");
     request.open("POST", "ajax.php", false);
     request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     request.send("act=get_set&ans="+ans);
     return request.responseText;
 }
 var settings = get_settings("");
 alert(settings)
```

Comment: Значит, чтобы функция get_settings возвращала request.responseText сделать не возможно?

Comment: возможно, но не нужно. 

+вам уже 2 раза упомянули как это можно сделать.

Comment: Спасибо.

Я просто этого языка не знаю, поэтому туплю по-жесткому

Comment: Очень многие его не знают, а еще больше людей думаю что его знают :D

Да, js не такой как все xD