# Переменная в функции в js

Tags: javascript, переменные

Есть глобальная переменная `var find;` есть функция, где я меняю значение глобальной переменной

```
function getMe(){
    data={action:'myInfo'};
    $.post('core.php', data, function(response){
        obj= JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            find = value['find'];
        });
    });
 }
```

И если я вызываю функцию

```
getMe();
console.log(find);
```

то в консоле `undefined`, почему так?

Comment: Потому что "асинхронность". `console.log(find);` выполняется раньше, чем `function(response){ ... }`.

Comment: Как с этим бороться? ) setTimeout?

Comment: Два пути: функции обратного вызова (callback) либо Обещания (Promise).

Comment: Таких вопросов уже over 9000 было. Вот один из них http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/68795/182771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Аякс запрос ушел на обработку, а ответ  получен/обработан будет после выполнения текущей функции

Comment: Как с этим бороться? ) setTimeout?

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан все ваши дальнейшие действия делайте в колбеке `function(response)`.

Comment: С этим бороться просто — лучше в инете подробно почитать, что такое Ajax и как с ним работать в тех или иных случаях